# r aggregate dataframe: some columns unchanged, some columns aggregated

Tags: r, aggregate

I have tried to look at manuals for aggregate, apply, etc, but I can't find examples where some columns are skipped by the function being applied, while other columns are copied as-is. Example:

```
> olddf = data.frame(code=c("one","one","two"), val1=c(1,2,3), val2=c(4,5,6), val3=c(7,8,9))
> olddf
  code val1 val2 val3
1  one    1    4    7
2  one    2    5    8
3  two    3    6    9
>
```

How do I aggregate olddf so that I get a new data frame where:

- **code** column is **kept as-is**,
- **val1** is **skipped**
- **val2** is aggregated normally e.g. **sum**()
- and ***a new column*** is created based on one of the earlier aggregates... e.g. new column = sum(val3)/sum(val2)?

I basically want:

```
> newdf
  code val2 newcol
1  one    9 1.6666
2  two    6 1.5000
```

I would like to do this in one step rather than defining a separate function to deal with each column / aggregate. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(olddf)[, .(val2 = sum(val2),
                 newcol = sum(val3)/sum(val2)), by = code]
#    code val2   newcol
# 1:  one    9 1.666667
# 2:  two    6 1.500000
```

Comment: When I try it with the example data i posted, it works. However, generalizing to my actual dataset gives the error: Error in as.vector(x, "list") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list' :-( I'm going to accept the answer though as it does give the example result.

Comment: UPDATE: I had a typo - got it working. Great!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps, the key is using the aggregate function. In the by() argument, you want to specify how you want to aggregate. In this case, aggregate according to the value in "Code". Then, add third column just by specifying the function of interest.

```
aggregate <- aggregate(olddf[, c("val2", "val3")], by = list(olddf$code), FUN = sum)
aggregate$newcol <- aggregate$val3/aggregate$val2
```

Comment: Hi - thanks very much. This seems to work but leaves the unwanted columns intact.