# R- Aggregate rows according to several values, but apply sum function only to some columns

Tags: r

I know there is a similar question ([r aggregate dataframe: some columns unchanged, some columns aggregated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509118/r-aggregate-dataframe-some-columns-unchanged-some-columns-aggregated)), but it doesn't work for what I need.

I have a dataframe with observations of different species, but many observations are from the same point (same longitude and latitude).

```
df=data.frame(sampleID=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),latitude=c(46.4,46.4,73.2,36.6,36.6,55.3), longitud=c(66.4,66.4,34.6,46.4,46.4,50.7), material=c("soil","soil","water","water","water","water"), biome=c("forest", "forest", "sea","sea","sea","lake"), sp1=c(2,1,0,4,0,0),sp2=c(0,2,3,1,0,1), sp3=c(0,1,1,4,3,0))

df
  sampleID latitude longitud material  biome sp1 sp2 sp3
1        a     46.4     66.4     soil forest   2   0   0
2        b     46.4     66.4     soil forest   1   2   1
3        c     73.2     34.6    water    sea   0   3   1
4        d     36.6     46.4    water    sea   4   1   4
5        e     36.6     46.4    water    sea   0   0   3
6        f     55.3     50.7    water   lake   0   1   0
```

I would like to sum the observations (columns sp1,sp2, and sp3, in the example provided) from the same location and same type of material, but leaving the other columns the same. In the case of "biome" it should be the same value, so just the same, and in the case of sample ID keep one ID. Something like:

```
  sampleID latitude longitud material  biome sp1 sp2 sp3
1        a     46.4     66.4     soil forest   3   2   1
3        c     73.2     34.6    water    sea   0   3   1
4        d     36.6     46.4    water    sea   4   1   7
6        f     55.3     50.7    water   lake   0   1   0
```

I have tried with aggregate, with ddply, and with data.table and lapply. But I don't know how to apply the sum function only to a set of columns (6:8), therefore it fails. The aggregate gives me an error and ddply deletes the other columns which it cannot sum (ID and biome). And it orders the observations according to latitude, so finding out which ID was each one is a mess.

Some of the things I tried:

```
ddply(df, .(latitude, longitude, material), numcolwise(sum))   #This one deletes the columns which it cannot sum, ID and biome (and many other variables I haven't shown in this example)

aggregate(.~latitude+longitude+material,data=df,sum) #Gives an error
aggregate(cbind(df[,c(6:8)]) ~ as[,c(2,3,4)], data=df, sum) #Gives an error
```

Also, this is a simplified version of the data frame I have, I have more variables and more than 200 species, each one with its actual name in latin. I can't be typing all of them, I need the selection by df[,c(18:220)], or something like that, to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in base R:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        DF |>
          split(DF$longitud, DF$latitude, DF$material) |> 
          lapply(function(x) { 
            cbind(x[1:5][1,], t(apply(x[6:8], 2, sum, na.rm = TRUE)))})) |>
  `rownames<-`(1:4)

  sampleID latitude longitud material  biome sp1 sp2 sp3
1        d     36.6     46.4    water    sea   4   1   7
2        a     46.4     66.4     soil forest   3   2   1
3        f     55.3     50.7    water   lake   0   1   0
4        c     73.2     34.6    water    sea   0   3   1
```

The above solution without the native pipe:

```
DF <- do.call(rbind, 
              lapply(split(df, df$longitud, df$latitude, df$material), 
                     function(x) { 
                       cbind(x[1:5][1,], t(apply(x[6:8], 2, sum, na.rm = TRUE)))})) 

`rownames<-`(DF, seq_len(nrow(DF)))

  sampleID latitude longitud material  biome sp1 sp2 sp3
1        c     73.2     34.6    water    sea   0   3   1
2        d     36.6     46.4    water    sea   4   1   7
3        f     55.3     50.7    water   lake   0   1   0
4        a     46.4     66.4     soil forest   3   2   1
```

We can also do this with `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(DF[startsWith(names(DF), "sp")], 
          list(latitude = DF$latitude, 
               longitude = DF$longitud, 
               material = DF$material), 
          sum, na.rm = TRUE)

  latitude longitude material sp1 sp2 sp3
1     46.4      66.4     soil   3   2   1
2     73.2      34.6    water   0   3   1
3     36.6      46.4    water   4   1   7
4     55.3      50.7    water   0   1   0
```

Or if you would like to use a formula, we make use of `cbind` for numeric variables since they are more than one:

```
aggregate(cbind(DF$sp1, DF$sp2, DF$sp3) ~ longitud + latitude + material, 
          data = DF, sum)

  longitud latitude material V1 V2 V3
1     66.4     46.4     soil  3  2  1
2     46.4     36.6    water  4  1  7
3     50.7     55.3    water  0  1  0
4     34.6     73.2    water  0  3  1
```

And also if you are willing to use package `dplyr`, it would make the job much easier:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(latitude, longitud, material) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("sp"), ~ sum(.x))) %>%
  slice_head(n = 1) %>%
  arrange(sampleID)

# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Groups:   latitude, longitud, material [4]
  sampleID latitude longitud material biome    sp1   sp2   sp3
  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>    <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a            46.4     66.4 soil     forest     3     2     1
2 c            73.2     34.6 water    sea        0     3     1
3 d            36.6     46.4 water    sea        4     1     7
4 f            55.3     50.7 water    lake       0     1     0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The aggregate options remove the ID column, which I need. It's the same result than with the ddply. The first one should be what I need, but I get several errors, even with the example provided here. First, "unexpected '>' ". After removing the ">" (which I don't know what they're for, I'm not familiar with this kind of syntax), I get an  "Error in Ops.data.frame(DF, split(DF$longitud, DF$latitude, DF$material)) :   list of length 4 not meaningful"

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. If we would like to keep `sample ID` it has to be either among the grouping variables or among the ones we are applying a function on. The first one sounds reasonable but I didn't understand on what basis you chose `a` over `b` and `d` over `e` since they are of the same `material` and `lat/lon`. So in the first solution I just chose the first one.

Comment: `|>` is a native R pipe operator. We use it to forward the result of the previous operation and place it as the first argument of the following operation. You cannot remove it as the code falls apart but I can make an edit. By the way that unexpected token error is not preventing the code from execution it's just that your version of Rstudio does not recognize it and throws a warning sign like mine.

Comment: @fuseros I added a modified solution without the pipe.

Comment: Great, thank you @Anoushivaran R! The modified version works with the example data. I don't mind which ID it keeps, a or b, as long as it keeps one. I am still getting some errors with my data,  I hope I'll be able to fix them. The last 1:4  is because in the end you have 4 rows? How do you know that in advance (my original df has more than 1000)?  Also, regarding the "x[1:5][1,],"  I guess [1:5] are the columns I don't want to sum, what's the [1,]?

Comment: Oh you're welcome. I again modified the modified version so that it creates `id` numbers for your original data set instead of `1:4`. That was just a temporary solution to get the desired output, but this one is stable. With regard to `x[1:5][1,]`, `[1:5]` these are in fact those variables that are either among grouping ones or those you would like to keep and `[1,]` is choosing the first row of the resulting `x[1:5]` data set. You can for example omit `[1,]` to see how the result looks like without it.

Comment: You know `aggregate` function is like `summarize` in `dplyr` package, they apply a function on your selected columns but they won't keep variables that are not among grouping ones or the ones we apply function on. So I thought the first and second (modified) solution are better if you wanna keep one `sample ID` per group. Let me know if there is something I could do again.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, it worked in my data too =D.  I think it was giving me an error because in one of the 200 columns there was an space before the number, and it read it as character -.-      Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help.